# c# - SQL delete command?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

When I delete a record, it works. But when I close the program and open it again, actually the record is not deleted.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Upper_Stage_Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        con.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Delete Current Row of Database Open");

        if (MaxRows != 0)
        {
            SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Data_no='@inc'", con);

            try
            {
                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted");
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR: Could not delete record");
            }
            MaxRows--;
            if (inc != 0)
            {
                inc--;
                NavigationRecords();
            }
            else
            {
                if (MaxRows != 1)
                {
                    inc++;
                    NavigationRecords();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No Record");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Record");
        }

        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Delete Current Row of Database Closed");
        con.Dispose();
}
```

When I searched, some records can not be deleted because they are "master" record. How can I delete the record TRULY?

Comment: Could it be that each time you compile, a fresh copy (with the row present) is copied to the output directory and used by your program?

Answer (score 3):

you don't need quotes around '@inc':

```
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Data_no=@inc", con);
```

Also you needs to provide the value for the `@inc` parameter too.

```
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inc", inc); //inc is a variable that contain a value for the @inc parameter
```

Although specify the type directly and use the `Value` property is more better than `AddWithValue`. Check this for more details: [`Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)